# WiFi Router need to be Rebooted each time to Connect

Tags: networking, router, ip, wifi-configuration, web

I have 2 WiFi routers in my house. one of them is a modem + router, the other one is a spare I had. I configured the spare as an extender on the WiFi network to expand the reach. Basically, now I have 2 WiFi networks in my house, where the second router is connected to the main router through a CAT6 cable.

The problem is that each time I have to reconnect certain devices, like my laptop or my Google Home device, it shows "No Internet". After WiFi restart, the first time I connect the device it is fine, but say, if I put my PC on sleep mode and then reconnect, this problem arises. Same with the other devices too. This problem does not arise with mobile devices.

I'm more or less a newbie in these matters, and followed this tutorial to get it done. I have a very basic understanding of these things and would really appreciate some help from the pros xD.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some articles which describe the possible solutions to your issue.
You can try them to see if they could help.

[Wi-Fi Network Disappears After Sleep/Wake/Hibernate in Windows 10](http://woshub.com/internet-or-wifi-disconnected-after-sleep/#:%7E:text=PowerShellWindows%2010-,Wi%2DFi%20Network%20Disappears%20After%20Sleep,Wake%2FHibernate%20in%20Windows%2010&text=Update%20the%20Wi%2DFi%20Adapter,Restart%20WLAN%20AutoConfig%20Service)

[Windows 10 disconnects from Wi-Fi after Sleep Mode? Fix it now](https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-1-disconnects-wi-fi-sleep-mode/)

[8 Ways to Fix Wi-Fi Does­n’t Con­nect After Sleep in Win­dows 10](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-wi-fi-doesnt-connect-after-sleep-windows-10/)

Thanks,